# Change submit button position in form

Tags: css-grid

I am developing a form using Html and CSS. I have used grid to place my textboxes. But the problem I am facing is position of submit button. It is placed next to last textbox but I want it to be placed on the separate line at the end.

The complete code of my this form is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Form practice</title>

        <style>
            .container{
                max-width: 1000px;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
                padding: 1em;
            }

            .wrapper{
                box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(72,94,116,0.7);
            }

            .wrapper > *{
                padding: 1em;                   
            }

            .form-heading{
                background-color: grey;
            }

            .form-heading h3{
                text-align: center;
            }

            .contact form{
                display: grid;
                grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
                grid-gap: 10px;
            }

            .contact form label{
                display: block;
            }

            .contact form p{
                margin: 0;
            }

            .contact form .submit-btn{
                grid-column: 25%;
            }

            .contact form button, .conntact form input{
                width: 100%;
                padding: 1em;
                border: 1px solid;
            }

            .contact input[type=text]{
                height: 30px;
                width: 90%;

            }

            .contact form button{
                background-color: grey;
                color: white;
                border: 0;
                text-transform: uppercase;
            }

            .contact form button:hover, .contact form button:focus{
                background-color: silver;
                color: black;                   
                outline: 0;
                /*transition: background-color 1s ease-out; */
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="form-heading">
                    <h3>Form</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="contact">
                    <form>
                        <p>
                            <label>First Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="firstName">
                        </p>

                        <p>
                            <label>Last Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="lastName">
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <label>Email Address</label>
                            <input type="text" name="email">
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <label>Phone Number</label>
                            <input type="text" name="phone">
                        </p>

                        <p class="submit-btn">
                            <button>Submit</button>
                        </p>

                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please help me in this regard. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does the trick in your case.

```
.submit-btn {
    grid-row-start: 3;
    grid-column-start: 3;
    grid-column-end: 3;
}
```

But a few suggestions:

- Change your `<p>` with `<div>`. `<p>` is for paragraphs of text.
- Don't use `grid` for displaying a grid. It's very unflexible and makes stuff hard to read. Use `display: flex` instead. If you want to see a sample on how to use flex to display a grid you might wanna check out the Bootstrap grid system. ([Basic grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/grid/) and [implementation for form](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/forms/#form-grid). Actual [Bootstrap CSS](https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css))
- There is no real reason to invent your own grid system at all. Bootstrap's Grid system is just one of many already working grids. :)

Comment: Actually I have followed a youtube tutorial for this form.

Answer (score 0):

You Should Follow [This Grid Layout](https://www.sitepoint.com/seven-ways-you-can-place-elements-using-css-grid-layout/) Documentatoin for manage form element into specific position.